# gnu linker: file not recognized

Tags: assembly, makefile, nasm

this is my makefile:

```
obj =init3.o initfunc.o descriptor.o disk.o

init:$(obj)
     ld -o init.out $(obj)

init3.o:init3.asm
        nasm -f aout init3.asm

initfunc.o:initfunc.asm
        nasm -f aout  initfunc.asm

descriptor.o:../lib/descriptor.asm
    nasm -f aout  ../lib/descriptor.asm

disk.o:../drive/disk.asm
    nasm -f aout  ../drive/disk.asm
```

they compiled totally nothing wrong,but when the linker started to link,an error came out:`file not recognized: file format not recognized.`
then I change every file to elf format by using `-f elf`,the error is still there,I googled that the GUN linker do recognize `.out` format,so what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Hazarding a guess.  Some of your files are not in the same directory.

Comment: `objdump -i` should give you a list of supported formats for ld. `nasm -hf` will list what Nasm will do. Something "should" match...

Comment: What CPU architecture is that (any chance of a 32/64bit mixup)? Please change to -f elf if your system is a BSD or GNU/Linux, then add the output of running `file *.o` to the listing. Also run `cc -o empty.o empty.c` on a mostly empty file, and run `file` on it. This shows what GNU ld is most likely to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW: delete your `.o` files before re-running `make`. It is all too easy to forget this after adjusting the compiler flags. (I'm talking from experience here...)

Explanation: adjusting the `makefile` will *not* enforce a recompilation (unless you specify `makefile` itself as a dependency in every rule in the `makefile`; which may not even be such a bad idea). Chances are you were linking the same old object files over and over again.